# Probability of HHTH possibly switching between normal and weighted coin after each flip

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble solving this question: Your friend has two coins: one is a normal coin which lands heads $50\%$ of the time, the other is a weighted coin which lands heads $75\%$ of the time.
When your friend starts flipping his coins, he’s equally likely to start with either coin, and switches coins with $30\%$ probability.

Find $P(HHTH)$

My solution:
$P(H)P(H)P(T)P(H)=(0.5(0.5+.75))(0.3(0.5+0.75))(0.3(0.5+.25))(0.3(0.5+.75))=0.0198$

At first it is equally likely to start with either coin, so I am using $0.5$.
But, then we switch coins with $30\%$ probability, so I am using $0.3$.

I think, if we don't switch it will be $70\%$ probability, but I am not sure how to use this info in formula. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself making slips regarding independence (or the lack thereof) so I broke the problem up into 16 cases based on the possibilities for the sequence of four fair or biased coin tosses.  The results are summarized in the following table. (I used a spreadsheet to do the calculations.)
$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Fairness} & \Pr(\text{Fairness}) & \Pr(\text{HHTH|Fairness}) & \Pr(\text{Fairness and HHTH}) \\
FFFF & 0.1715 & 0.062500 & 0.010719 \\
FFFB & 0.0735 & 0.093750 & 0.006891 \\
FFBF & 0.0315 & 0.031250 & 0.000984 \\
FFBB & 0.0735 & 0.046875 & 0.003445 \\
FBFF & 0.0315 & 0.093750 & 0.002953 \\
FBFB & 0.0135 & 0.140625 & 0.001898 \\
FBBF & 0.0315 & 0.046875 & 0.001477 \\
FBBB & 0.0735 & 0.070313 & 0.005168 \\
BFFF & 0.0735 & 0.093750 & 0.006891 \\
BFFB & 0.0315 & 0.140625 & 0.004430 \\
BFBF & 0.0135 & 0.046875 & 0.000633 \\
BFBB & 0.0315 & 0.070313 & 0.002215 \\
BBFF & 0.0735 & 0.140625 & 0.010336 \\
BBFB & 0.0315 & 0.210938 & 0.006645 \\
BBBF & 0.0735 & 0.070313 & 0.005168 \\
BBBB & 0.1715 & 0.105469 & 0.018088 \\
     &        & Total         & 0.087939 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
In the third row, for example, starting FFBF, the probability of fair - fair - biased - fair is $(.5) (.7) (.3) (.3) = 0.0315$.  Given that sequence of fair / biased coins, the probability of HHTH is $(.5)(.5)(.25)(.5) = 0.03125$.  Then the probability of FFBF and HHTH is $(0.0315)(0.03125) = 0.000984$.  The other rows are calculated similarly.

When the probabilities of all the cases are added up, the final probability of getting HHTH is $0.087939$.

Comment: Thank you so much! you have made it very clear.

Answer (score 2):

If we start with the balanced coin, then the probability of getting a head at any subsequent stage is 
$$
P(H)=0.7\cdot 0.5+0.3\cdot 0.75=0.575
$$
and we can model you situation with a single weighted coin with $P(H)=0.575$ and $P(T)=0.425$. Thus
$$
P(HHTH)=0.5(0.575)^2(0.425)\approx 0.0703.
$$

If we start with the unbalanced coin, then the probability of getting a head at any subsequent stage is 
$$
P(H)=0.7\cdot 0.75+0.3\cdot 0.5=0.675
$$
and we can model you situation with a single weighted coin with $P(H)=0.675$ and $P(T)=0.325$. Thus
$$
P(HHTH)=0.75(0.675)^2(0.325)\approx 0.1111.
$$

Finally since we are equally likely to start with either coin, the total probability is
$$
P(HHTH)\approx 0.5\cdot 0.0703 + 0.5\cdot 0.1111 = 0.0907.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Could you please explain why you are using 4C3 in the formula? And if you have assumed that we start with the balanced coin than why are you using P(H)=0.575 for the first toss also along with the rest three?

Comment: You know what, I shouldn't have used $\binom{4}{3}$. That is the probability of getting $3$ heads, not the specific sequence $HHTH$. Also, the first toss should use the proper probabilities of the coin we start with. Both changes are reflected in my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{h_i\}_{i=1}^4$ be the probability of heads in the 4 tosses. The probability of switching coins between tosses is $s = \dfrac{1}{3}$.
$$ \mathbb{P}(\textrm{HHTH}) 
= \sum_{h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4 \in \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\}}\mathbb{P}(\textrm{HHTH}|h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4)\; \mathbb{P}(h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4) $$
The coin chosen for a certain toss is statistically independent of the all the tosses expect the preceding one. This means we can simplify $\mathbb{P}(h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4)  \equiv \mathbb{P}(h_4|h_3,h_2,h_1) \mathbb{P}(h_3|h_2,h_1) \mathbb{P}(h_2|h_1) \mathbb{P}(h_1) $ to  $\mathbb{P}(h_4|h_3) \mathbb{P}(h_3|h_2) \mathbb{P}(h_2|h_1) \mathbb{P}(h_1)$. If the probability of switching is $s$, then $\mathbb{P}(h_{k+1}|h_k) = s $ if there was a switching, i.e., $h_{k+1} \neq h_{k}$, and $ = 1-s $ if there was no switching, i.e., $h_{k+1} = h_{k}$. In other words, $\mathbb{P}(h_{k+1}|h_k)  = s \mathbb{1}_{h_{k+1} \neq h_{k}} + (1-s) \mathbb{1}_{h_{k+1} = h_{k}} = s (1-\mathbb{1}_{h_{k+1} = h_{k}}) + (1-s) \mathbb{1}_{h_{k+1} = h_{k}} = s + (1-2s)\mathbb{1}_{h_{k+1} = h_{k}}$.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4) 
&= \mathbb{P}(h_4|h_3)\;\mathbb{P}(h_3|h_2)\;\mathbb{P}(h_2|h_1)\;\mathbb{P}(h_1) \\
&= [s+ (1-2s)\mathbb{1}_{h_4=h_3}][s+ (1-2s)\mathbb{1}_{h_3=h_2}][s+ (1-2s)\mathbb{1}_{h_2=h_1}]\frac{1}{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{54}[1+ \mathbb{1}_{h_4=h_3}][1+ \mathbb{1}_{h_3=h_2}][1+ \mathbb{1}_{h_2=h_1}]\\
\mathbb{P}(\textrm{HHTH}) 
&= \frac{1}{54} \sum_{h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4 \in \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\}} h_1h_2(1-h_3)h_4\;[1+ \mathbb{1}_{h_4=h_3}][1+ \mathbb{1}_{h_3=h_2}][1+ \mathbb{1}_{h_2=h_1}]\\
&=\frac{35}{432} \approx 0.08 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Could you please explain how you have calculated P(h1,h2,h3,h4). What does terms like [s+(1−2s)1h4=h3] mean?

Comment: @New_Coder I have added some more details to my answer.

Comment: How are you getting s(1−1hk+1=hk) from s1hk+1≠hk in equation P(hk+1|hk)=s1hk+1≠hk+(1−s)1hk+1=hk=s(1−1hk+1=hk)+(1−s)1hk+1=hk=s+(1−2s)1hk+1=hk?

Comment: $$\mathbb{1}_{x=y} \equiv \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } x =y \\  0 & \textrm{if } x \neq y \end{cases} $$ Similarly, $$\mathbb{1}_{x \neq y} \equiv \begin{cases} 0 & \textrm{if } x =y \\  1 & \textrm{if } x \neq y \end{cases} $$ Or $$ \mathbb{1}_{x=y} + \mathbb{1}_{x \neq y} = 1$$